# How to delete a list's view programatically in C#, Sharepoint 2010?

Tags: c#, view, sharepoint-2010

How can I delete a SharePoint List views programatically?

MyCustomView: is a custom view created by me programatically. I want to delete all view created with same name

```
using (SPSite oSPsite = new SPSite("http://xxxxxxxxxx:20000/sites/myWA/test"))
                {                    
                    using (SPWeb oSPWeb = oSPsite.OpenWeb())
                    {
                        SPList oTransDataList = oSPWeb.Lists["MyDataList"];
                        oSPWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;                        
                        SPViewCollection oViewCollection = oTransDataList.Views;
                        int i = 1;
                        foreach (SPView oViewColl in oViewCollection)
                        {
                            if (oViewColl.Title == "MyCustomView")
                                {
                                    oViewCollection.Delete(oViewColl.ID);

                                    //oTransDataList.Views.Delete(oViewColl.ID); 
                                    oTransDataList.Update();

                                }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

I noticed `SPViewCollection oViewCollection = oTransDataList.Views;` containing 1 view only. May I know why so happening I have more than 10 views out of which 9 views are custom with same name. ie. MyCustomView

Comment: The above snippet is the correct answer now. I have modified the wrong code with correct (working code)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are on the right track. However, I would recommend doing this in two steps. First, collect the desired views. Second, delete the views. The problem with combining the steps is that the collection you are looping through changes once you delete a view.

```
using (SPSite oSPsite = new SPSite("http://xxxxxxxxxx:20000/sites/myWA/test"))
{                    
    using (SPWeb oSPWeb = oSPsite.OpenWeb())
    {
        SPList oTransDataList = oSPWeb.Lists["MyDataList"];
        oSPWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;                        
        List<Guid> ids = new List<Guid>();
        SPViewCollection oViewCollection = oTransDataList.Views;
        foreach (SPView oViewColl in oViewCollection)
        {
            if (oViewColl.Title == "MyCustomView")
            {
                ids.Add(oViewColl.ID);
            }
        }
        foreach (Guid id in ids)
        {
            oViewCollection.Delete(id);
        }
    }
}
```

As another alternative, you might be able to combine the steps, if you step through the collection backwards:

```
for (int i = oViewCollection.Count - 1; i >= 0; --i)
{
    SPView oViewColl = oViewCollection[i];
    if (oViewColl.Title == "MyCustomView")
    {
        oViewCollection.Delete(oViewColl.ID);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Rich, The code with second approach, you have provided worked well for me.. 
Thank You So much for the help

Answer (score 0):

I have created views progarmatically with the same name 10times and tested it is showing me 10 views
SPViewCollection oViewCollection = oTransDataList.Views.

```
 using (SPSite oSPsite = new SPSite("http://SampletestSite.com/Trial"))
        {
            oSPsite.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;

            using (SPWeb oSPWeb = oSPsite.OpenWeb())
            {
                oSPWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                SPList list = oSPWeb.Lists["Sample"];
               StringCollection strViewFields = new StringCollection();
                    strViewFields.Add("Title");
                    strViewFields.Add("FirstName");
                    strViewFields.Add("LastName");

            // create a standard view with the set of fields defined in the collection
               list.Views.Add("SampleTest", strViewFields, String.Empty,
                        100, true, false, SPViewCollection.SPViewType.Html, false);

               list.Update();

         oSPWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
    }

oSPsite.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
 }
```

In your code comment below line and try executing
 oTransDataList.Views.Delete(oViewColl.ID); // gives error id not matching
Add watch for oViewCollection.Count and check,you can even verify the title by adding watch for oViewCollection[index]

Comment: Hi Suchithra, The code you have provided is for creation of view which I am not looking for. But the comment you provided below your code is helpful.                               oTransDataList.Views.Delete(oViewColl.ID); is actually not required Thank YOu SO much for the help